# Does JGit have a shortlog command?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I need to be able to execute this command from a Java program

```
git shortlog -s -n --all --no-merges --since="01 Nov 2019"
```

I see that JGit has a LogCommand class, but it does not have a ShortLogCommand class. Is this possible to do in JGit or not? And if so, could anyone point me in the right direction of how I could do this? Thank you!

EDIT: Found a way to do this without JGit, you can use ProcessBuilder to execute Git commands from Java. Set the process to the path of the git bash terminal.